# How to turn off desktop icons in Ubuntu 19.04 or 19.10

Tags: 19.04, gnome-shell, 19.10, gnome-shell-extension, desktop-icons

I have the extension turned OFF (see ❶), but still the icons are there (see ❷)!

[image: screenshot]

I can get rid of them if I uninstall the extension with

```bsh
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
```

But they'll come back with an upgrade. I can force them not to like:

```
sudo apt-mark hold gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
```

But then I get a massive red ⛔ icon permanently telling me my system is broken.

Why won't it behave? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of sheer frustration that this still doesn't work in 19.10, I'm hacking the file at `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/extension.js`

Simply putting `return;` as the first line after  `function enable() {`

✔ Icons gone.

They *will* come back with an upgrade, but at least I've not broken apt dependencies (!) or caused a big red permanaent system broken sign.

Answer (score 1):

First install vanilla gnome. (This step may be optional, but I cannot verify because this is just the path I took.)

```
sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop
```

Now restart your system with the new vanilla gnome.

Then remove the extension.  This will remove some meta packages, but don't worry.  It will not break anything.

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
```

Now I rebooted here, but it is probably not required.  Now open the gnome shell extension website.  I do this on my system by clicking the little foot icon in firefox.  Then I simply click the red X button.

You should no longer have the extension.

I am on 19.10..for reference.

Just as a side note.  Removing that package actually makes the extension work properly and it can then be enabled and disabled.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want a whole different desktop environment (I know they're very similar but there are things that dont work on vanilla gnome!)

Comment: Like what exactly?

Comment: the systray/appindicators - these are essential to me (signal, nextcloud, mattermost, skype..) and historically I've had problems with vanilla gnome (which I always used until that point)

Comment: I still have those extensions.  I mean I can double check, but I am pretty sure all gnome extensions still work as normal.

Comment: so far so good. (although now I can't get the icons to appear at all - meh). maybe they sorted the problems with ubuntu-app-indicators under gnome vanilla. thx

Answer (score 0):

Try gnome-extensions-app to switch off original desktop icons by csoriano.

I had the same problem and found the solution here:
[How can I hide Desktop Icons with Ubuntu 20.04 without additional programs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274861/how-can-i-hide-desktop-icons-with-ubuntu-20-04-without-additional-programs)