# How can I hide Desktop Icons with Ubuntu 20.04 without additional programs?

Tags: 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 with the "minimal installation" setup-option. On my desktop I can see my home folder and the trash. I want to hide both, without installing any additional software.
I already tried in the console **gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false** but it does not seem to have any effect. I restartet my system afterwards, hoping that a restart of the window system (or GUI) would fix or reload the config, but both icons are still visible. I checked the value of show-home and it is set to false, but this value does not seem to matter, as far as I can tell.
**Is there another config that needs editing?**
I typed in the command exactly as I wrote, without any sudo, since I want to change my Desktop.

Comment: Actually I installed 20.04.1 (LTS), and I installed every update they have released so far.

Comment: I just tried **gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage** which did work, so gsettings seems to be somewhat working. I some other program overruling gsettings when it comes to the desktop?

Comment: **gnome-extensions prefs desktop-icons@csoriano** opens a config Dialog which lets me disable the home and trash icon. That program seems to overrule gsettings. No both icons are gone. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Search for extension app
- Find `Desktop Icons` in the list of installed extensions
- Turn off the toggle.

[image]

- Done!

Comment: I can not find the extension app. Maybe this app is not included in the minimal installation setup. Is there a way to do this via the Settings or by changing a value in some file?

Comment: Alternatively, Do you have `gnome-tweaks` installed?

Comment: No, but the console app gnome-extensions. Apparently via this gnome-extensions thing there is an extension **desktop-icons@csoriano** installed. Maybe this is the problem ...

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right way. Configuring gnome-extensions worked just fine, without needing to install anything. :)

Comment: For Ubuntu 23.10, open a terminal and run `gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com`

Answer (score 1):

I know @Thomas already has found an answer by himself, but maybe this can help someone using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (which apparently does not come, by deafault, with the "extensions" GUI app shortcut).

In a terminal, type:

```
gnome-extensions prefs desktop-icons@csoriano
```

This will open a GUI in which you can set which icons to show (home and trash) and in which size (small/normal/big)